# Couldn't work ccxt package

Tags: google-cloud-platform, python

I'm a beginner.

I have a problem in google Cloud Functions service. I want to use ccxt python package but from this week it couldn't deploy my python program. In cloud Functions log page

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/bin/functions-framework", line 8, in  sys.exit(_cli()) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in **call** return self.main(*args, **kwargs) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main rv = self.invoke(ctx) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke return callback(*args, **kwargs) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/functions_framework/_cli.py", line 37, in _cli app = create_app(target, source, signature_type) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/functions_framework/**init**.py", line 172, in create_app spec.loader.exec_module(source_module) File "", line 783, in exec_module File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed File "/workspace/main.py", line 2, in  import ccxt File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ccxt/**init**.py", line 29, in  from ccxt.base.exchange import Exchange # noqa: F401 File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ccxt/base/**init**.py", line 24, in  from ccxt.base import exchange File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ccxt/base/exchange.py", line 40, in  from ccxt.static_dependencies import ecdsa File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ccxt/static_dependencies/ecdsa/**init**.py", line 1, in  from .keys import SigningKey, VerifyingKey, BadSignatureError, BadDigestError File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ccxt/static_dependencies/ecdsa/keys.py", line 3, in  from . import ecdsa File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ccxt/static_dependencies/ecdsa/ecdsa.py", line 56, in  from six import int2byte, b ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'

so I wonder this problem from ccxt but couldn't solve it...

Comment: Do you have package `six` in `pip list`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to install six?

```
pip3 install six
```